# Is it still protecting against code injection/XSS if I use HttpUtility.HtmlEncode followed by HtmlDecode?

Tags: c#, html, .net, model-view-controller

I'm working through the MVC example in the dotnet documentation https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/first-mvc-app/start-mvc?view=aspnetcore-8.0&tabs=visual-studio and read through the documentation for HttpUtility, but I don't think my question is answered in the docs.

I found that if I HtmlEncode() a string with special characters in it, they are still printed as their numeric equivalent (e.g. a single quote is ') but if I run it through both HtmlEncode() and HtmlDecode, it prints correctly.

1. Is this still safe, or will javascript and the like survive the roundtrip?
2. Is there a better way to achieve a plain-text encoded string in my c# code rather than having to remember the html numerical character?

For clarity:

```
public string Welcome(string name, int numTimes = 1)
    {
        var tempString = HttpUtility.HtmlEncode($"Hello {name}, this is the {numTimes} time you've viewed this page");
        return tempString; //this displays the numerical character for a single quote
        return HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(tempString); //this displays a single quote/parentheses correctly.
    }
```

Comment: The function returns a standard string. The really big question is: What do you do with that string, like send it to the client as html or what? Show the code!

Comment: @PoulBak this is a boilerplate dotnet MVC project, so the Welcome function is an endpoint that prints the returned text to an otherwise blank page. Showing you the code would require copy/pasting a few other files.